# Julia ALOHA simulation

Tags: plot, julia, aloha

I want to write ALOHA simulation but I plot this picture only G=0 1 2 3.What I need to add?

```
using Plots
A = []
for G in 0.0:3.0
S = G*ℯ^(-2G) 
push!(A, S)
end
println(A)
plot(A)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code could be written like this, is this what you need?:

```
using Plots
G=0.0:0.01:3.0
A= G.*ℯ.^(-2G)
plot(G,A)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
using Plots
plot(x -> x * exp(-2x), 0, 3)
```

which also gives

[image]